# Get the last transaction from the blockchain

Tags: nodeos, transactions, javascript

I'm looking for a way to get the latest transaction recorded on a particular account.
For example, I'm trying to get the latest transaction for "newdexpocket", how can I do that using nodejs?

Here's my code so far (-1 for pos isn't working, unfortunately):

```
const Eos = require('eosjs');

// Connect to a testnet or mainnet
const chain = {
    main: 'aca376f206b8fc25a6ed44dbdc66547c36c6c33e3a119ffbeaef943642f0e906', // main network
    jungle: '038f4b0fc8ff18a4f0842a8f0564611f6e96e8535901dd45e43ac8691a1c4dca', // jungle testnet
    sys: 'cf057bbfb72640471fd910bcb67639c22df9f92470936cddc1ade0e2f2e7dc4f' // local developer
};

const config = {
    expireInSeconds: 60,
    broadcast: true,
    verbose: false,
    sign: true,
    debug: false,
    httpEndpoint: 'https://api.eosnewyork.io',
    chainId: chain.main,
    //keyProvider: ['PrivateKeys...'], // WIF string or array of keys.. 
};

//const eos = Eos(config);
const eos = Eos(config);

eos.getActions("newdexpocket", 100000, 100).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(error => {
    console.error(error)
});
```

Comment: Can you add a link to the documentation or source for this method? If you're referring to the history plugin, I think it is being deprecated and other methods will better suite your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did some research on my side as well and you're right, the plugin is being deprecated so I'll have to follow your advise and seek for alternative elsewhere ;-) Just in case, would you happen to know what's suppose to replace the history_plugin?

Answer (score 1):

This may have change since you asked this question, however -1 for pos should work as expected.

Example using curl to get most recent action for `newdexpocket`:

`curl --request POST --url https://nodes.get-scatter.com:443/v1/history/get_actions --header 'content-type: application/json' --data '{"pos":"-1","offset":"-1","account_name":"newdexpocket"}'`

Answer (score 0):

Demux is not a replacement for the history plugin but the right tool for this use case. Look for the demux example.